# Angular 8 - how to identify (and subscribe to) an element in a template passed into a component

Tags: angular, dom-events, angular2-template

I have a parent component that renders an "item" component, using a template to define the item's markup (I have stripped my scenario down to bare bones):

```
// parent component template

<item [model]="itemModel" [template]="itemTemplate"></item>

<ng-template #itemTemplate let-model="model">
    <div>AAA {{model.property1}}</div>
    <div>BBB {{model.property2}}</div>
    <div>CCC {{model.property3}}</div>
</ng-template>
```

```
// "item" component template

<ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="template" [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{model: model}"></ng-container>
```

Inside the "item" component code, I need to subscribe to the click event of one of the elements inside the #itemTemplate (e.g. the "AAA" div).
The catch is that it is the parent component that defines which of the elements in the #itemTemplate is to be subscribed to. This can be hardcoded in the parent component by the developer (how exactly to do that is part of the question here).
At the same time, the click handler needs to be inside the "item" component (to encapsulate the click handling functionality - the parent component needn't be concerned with that).

I tried three ways how to do this, but I don't like either and I wonder if there is a better way. These 3 attempts are independent of each other.

### 1. use a template ref variable

**The idea:** just as #itemTemplate reference is used to identify the template, use the same syntax to create a reference to the desired component (to subscribe to).
Then pass the reference on to the "item" component via a new @Input.

```
// parent component template
// the "item" component now takes an additional input "subscribeToThis"

<item [model]="itemModel" [template]="itemTemplate" [subscribeToThis]="subscribeToThis"></item>

<ng-template #itemTemplate let-model="model">

    // the #subscribeToThis reference on the div below is used above as the value
    // for the subscribeToThis input of the child component;
    // but it's always undefined ...

    <div #subscribeToThis >AAA {{model.property1}}</div>
    <div>BBB {{model.property2}}</div>
    <div>CCC {{model.property3}}</div>
</ng-template>
```

**Result/problem:** in the "item" component, the subscribeToThis is undefined. (I think it was undefined because of the scope of the #subscribeToThis reference - am I right ?) Therefore the "item" component can't use this to find the element to subscribe to.

Similar to this, with the same result - I tried finding the #subscribeToThis reference in the "item" component class like this:

```
// bits from child component class

@ViewChild('subscribeToThis', {static: false}) elementToSubscribeTo: TemplateRef<any>;

  ngAfterViewInit() {

    // this.elementToSubscribeTo is undefined here;
    // if "things worked", this.elementToSubscribeTo would refer to the element to whose click event I need to subscibe to

  }
```

but elementToSubscribeTo was again undefined.

### 2. use css class to mark and find the element

**The idea:** assign a special class ("subscribe-to-this" in the example below) to the desired #itemTemplate element:

```
// parent component template
<ng-template #itemTemplate let-model="model">

    // note the class on this div; you can use low-level tools to find the element
    // by its class, but that's not "clean angular"

    <div class="subscribe-to-this">AAA {{model.property1}}</div>
    <div>BBB {{model.property2}}</div>
    <div>CCC {{model.property3}}</div>
</ng-template>
```

Then, in the "item" component, have ElementRef and Renderer2 injected into it. Using them, I can find the element by class and then subscribe to its click event.

**Result/success:**  the "item" component will find the element and the subscription to the element's click event does trigger the click handler in the "item" component.

**The problem with this approach:** this low level approach is discouraged for good reasons.

### 3. assign the click handler directly in the element in the template

**The idea:**

```
// parent component template
<ng-template #itemTemplate let-model="model">

    // the click handler is assigned right here in the template;
    // note that the event handler is a function on the model
    // that is passed to the child component; that function needs to be
    // added to the model "artificially" since the model shouldn't need to be aware
    // of how it's handled in the "item" component; that's one of the bad points
    // in this attempt

    <div (click)="model.clickHandler()">AAA {{model.property1}}</div>
    <div>BBB {{model.property2}}</div>
    <div>CCC {{model.property3}}</div>
</ng-template>
```

For this to work, the clickHandler() function has to be added to the model (e.g. in the "item" component's onNgInit). The reason for this gymnastics is the relatively simple usage in the #itemTemplate.

**Result/success:** the clickHandler() is called when the correct element is clicked.

**The issues with this approach:**

- The parent component must know the magic function name. This is not a deal breaker, but is a step away from a nice clean black-box component.
- If the consumer (parent) needs to work with the itemModel data afterwards, the 
  "add-on" function clickHandler() isn't nice to have in there. It's not nice when the parent gets the data back with some "garbage" added to it. I know I can delete it from the object, but that feels like the start of a rabbit hole.

### Conclusion

I am new to Angular and I am hoping I am just missing some technique that would let me implement this cleanly while keeping the "item" component as "black-boxy" as possible.
Thanks for any ideas or insights.

Comment: Can you explain your problem more clearly? I was not clear what was broken from the first paragraph, and too much there to try to wade through and find it.

Comment: @theMayer The 3 attempts are independent of each other (I now updated the question to that affect). What specifically could be made clearer please ? I'd love to improve the question, but it is kinda complicated (in my mind at least).

Comment: I added the child component template code to the question, and added comments to other code chunks, to hopefully make it clearer.

Comment: Generally when I see “this works” then my next question is “what is the issue” or “what are you trying to accomplish.” I’ll sit down at my desk and take a look at it in the morning and see if I can make sense of it.

Comment: I see, thanks - I edited the question to make it more exact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to provide the click method in the context, e.g.

```
// "item" component template
<ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="template" [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{model: model, onClickItem: doStuffWhenClick}"></ng-container>
```

```
// "item" component ts file
public doStuffWhenClick(...) { ... }
```

```
// parent component template

<item [model]="itemModel" [template]="itemTemplate"></item>

<ng-template #itemTemplate let-model="model" let-onClickItem="onClickItem">
    <div (click)="onClickItem()">AAA {{model.property1}}</div>
    <div>BBB {{model.property2}}</div>
    <div>CCC {{model.property3}}</div>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: This is great, thanks @Xinan ! To tie this to my question, it's the attempt #3 but with decoupling the model from the click handler. The model doesn't need any additional "stuff". The template does need the additional let-onClickItem (a step away from black box-iness), but that's paid off by the untouched model. In case it helps anyone, here's Xinan's idea, with additional modifications I need for my use case. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z1kv6c.

Comment: Pretty sure you'll need to bind the "doStuffWhenClick" method to the right "this" context when passing it around, e.g. `onClickItem: this.doStuffWhenClick.bind(this)`.

Answer (score 1):

In Angular, the way to notify the parent that an event has occurred is to use the `@Ouput` decorator inside of your child component.

Ex.
Child component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `<button (click)='mycustomEvent.emit('foo')'>Click me</button>`,
})
export class HelloComponent  {
  @Output() mycustomEvent = new EventEmitter();
}
```

Parent Component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<hello (mycustomEvent)="handleEvent($event)"></hello>`,
})
export class AppComponent  {
  handlEvent(event) {
    console.log(event);
  }
}
```

[Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ljmbwy)

Now you can keep your click functionality encapsulated inside the child and the parent can be notified from the child via `@Output`

Here is an example of how to do it with a service:
[Communicate via Service](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5gfz3z)

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks @Nico. Your answer actually helps to rephrase my question. You are describing how a child component can "let the parent know" about something (an event happened). My question is: how can the parent "let the child know" what element to subscribe to ? (is this making sense ?)

Comment: Well if you want to go from parent to child you can use inputs or you can use a service. The parent would push data in and the child would only read.

Comment: That's what I tried in my attempt #1 in my question (sorry if it wasn't clear enough). The input is called "subscribeToThis", and the parent "sends" the template reference to that input. However, the value was always undefined in the child. This is possibly an issue with the nature of what the value was (a template reference, rather than just a string or a number), but that's just a guess. If there was a way to get the reference across to the child (and assuming there was a way, in the child, to subscribe to that reference's click event), that would be a nice simple solution...

Comment: I updated my answer with another stackblitz that highlights how to communicate to child from parent using a service

Comment: Thanks @Nico. I am looking at your latest stackblitz, and I get "ERROR
Error: _co.handleEvent is not a function" when I click the "Click me" button. I tried to tweak a few things but couldn't fix it. Does it work for you ?
I also noticed that there is an "inline" template defined in the component directive, but the template file is there as well. I tried both, same issue.

Comment: I updated the link once again and removed all the unnecessary.
I just did a quick thing to illustrate the solution.

Answer (score 1):

In the interest of keeping the item component as "black-boxy" as possible I am going to suggest the usage of ng-content / content-projection to solve this.

We will no longer be using an ng-template, instead your item component will have an ng-content (creates a content projection slot) inside it's template, and the parent component will use this content projection slot to render what was previously in the ng-template.

**Parent component class:**

```
export class ParentComponent {
  numberOfClicks = 0;

  onClick() {
    this.numberOfClicks++;
  }

}
```

**Parent component template:**

```
<p>Some parent html</p>

<app-item [clickEvent]="numberOfClicks">
  <div>AAA</div>
  <div (click)="onClick()">BBB</div>
  <div>CCC</div>
</app-item>

<p>Some other parent html</p>
```

**Item component class:**

```
export class ItemComponent implements OnChanges {
  @Input() clickEvent: any;

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if (changes.clickEvent.currentValue) {
      console.log('Write whatever code you want to run on the click event here');
    }
  }

}
```

**Item component template**

```
<p>Some item HTML</p>
<ng-content></ng-content>
<p>Some more item HTML</p>
```

I know this is not exactly what you asked for, but I believe it will be a good approach to your problem. A good article about content projection can be read here: https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-ng-content/

Comment: Thank you @SnorreDan. For now I marked Xinan's as the accepted answer, because it gets me going right away, but I will study your suggestion and if a solution comes out of it that's even better, I'll change the accepted answer. You're right this is not exactly what I asked for (for the technical issue), but it's exactly what I asked for in terms or widening my angular horizons - thanks again.

Comment: That is good to hear @Rob. You stating that you were new to angular was the reason I thought this solution would be worth explaining